# Webpack error on start react app - linux mint

Tags: reactjs, linux, webpack, linux-mint

I'm running Linux Mint 19.2, npm 6.13.7, node 8.10.0, and firefox 70.0.1 I ran npm install, everything went correctly. Npm start throws this error. I'm running the same project side by side on a Mac without [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Meejq.png) issue. Has anyone had anything similar?
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Meejq.png)

Comment: You say "Npm start throws this error". Can you actually share the error with us?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure why the screenshot didn't upload. there's a link now

Comment: If the same project works on one platform (Mac) on not on the other (Linux), there might be a dependency issue. After you executed `npm install`, was there any error during the installation of packages?

Comment: There were no issues with installation, other than the standard npm warnings

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking function `Auth` instead of exporting it. Remove `()` from `export default Auth()`. This may fix your problem.

Comment: Failed to launch when I did that, and now, even having undone that one change, it won't even get as far as the browser. Going to pull the repo again.